# Worklight Unauthorized to PATH/common/query

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, worklight-adapters

Everything worked fine with 1 adapter.
Now I have 2 adapters and when I invoke them I get following errors:

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) http://10.99.10.54:10080/Klappr/apps/services/api/Klappr/common/query
    Request [/Klappr/apps/services/api/Klappr/common/query] worklight.js:1292

    response [/Klappr/apps/services/api/Klappr/common/query] success: /*-secure-
```

{"responseID":"2","statusCode":200,"isSuccessful":true,"statusReason":"OK","WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"ddu3aed2bvfmpg3b2spd369d2s","attributes": ...

The response works fine, but everything else in Dojo crashes after the response gets back.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are normal.  You should have been getting them even with 1 adapter.  Your dojo problem must be elsewhere.